Python, Tkinter: Apply delay to function inside generator
I am making an application in python tkinter to visualize algorithms. I want to apply a delay (window.after()) to the function partition() called inside quick_sort. The window.after() seems to only affect the "speed" of the quick_sort function. When running the program, setting the speed lower (with a higher number on the sort_speed scale), the program's speed fluctuates heavily. I presume the program is only delayed on 1 sorting part, but not the other?
Algorithms file:
"""Module to implement algorithms"""


def bubble_sort(data, draw_data):
    """Bubble sort algorithm"""

    size = len(data)

    for i in range(size):
        for j in range(0, size - i - 1):

            if data[j] > data[j + 1]:
                data[j], data[j + 1] = data[j + 1], data[j]

                draw_data(data, ['Green' if x == j + 1 else 'Red' for x in range(len(data))])
                yield

    draw_data(data, ['Green' for _ in range(len(data))])


def partition(data, draw_data, low, high):
    """Quick sort: Find partition position"""

    pivot = data[high]
    i = low - 1

    draw_data(data, get_color_array(len(data), low, high, i, i))

    for j in range(low, high):

        if data[j] <= pivot:
            draw_data(data, get_color_array(len(data), low, high, i, j, True))

            i += 1

            data[i], data[j] = data[j], data[i]

        draw_data(data, get_color_array(len(data), low, high, i, j))

    draw_data(data, get_color_array(len(data), low, high, i, low, True))

    data[i + 1], data[high] = data[high], data[i + 1]

    return i + 1


def quick_sort(data, draw_data, low, high):
    """Quick sort algorithm"""

    if low < high:
        pivot_index = partition(data, draw_data, low, high)

        yield

        yield from quick_sort(data, draw_data, low, pivot_index - 1)
        yield from quick_sort(data, draw_data, pivot_index + 1, high)


# Grey - Unsorted elements
# Blue - Pivot point element
# White - Sorted half/partition
# Red - Starting pointer
# Yellow - Ending pointer
# Green - All elements are sorted
def get_color_array(data_len, low, high, border, cur_id_x, is_swapping=False):
    """Quick sort: Get color for data"""
    
    color_array = []
    for i in range(data_len):

        if high <= i <= low:
            color_array.append('Grey')
        else:
            color_array.append('White')

        if i == low:
            color_array[i] = 'Blue'
        elif i == border:
            color_array[i] = 'Red'
        elif i == cur_id_x:
            color_array[i] = 'Yellow'

        if is_swapping:
            if i == border or i == cur_id_x:
                color_array[i] = 'Green'

    return color_array


Main file:
"""Module for visualizing data structures and algorithms"""


import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import HORIZONTAL
import random
import algorithms

def repeater(data_array, draw_data_update, speed_ms, gen=None):

    if not gen and navbar.curselection():

        algorithm.config(text=navbar.get(navbar.curselection()))

        match navbar.get(navbar.curselection()):
            case "Bubble sort":
                time_complexity.config(text="Time complexity: O(n^2)")
                gen = algorithms.bubble_sort(data_array, draw_data_update)
            case "Quick sort":
                time_complexity.config(text="Time complexity: O(n^2)")
                gen = algorithms.quick_sort(data_array, draw_data_update, 0, len(data_array) - 1)
            case _:
                pass

    try:
        next(gen)

        if running_animation:
            window.after(speed_ms, repeater, data_array, draw_data_update, speed_ms, gen)

        return

    except StopIteration:
        draw_data(data_array, ['Green' for _ in range(len(data))])


def regenerate():
    global data
    global running_animation

    if running_animation:
        running_animation = False

    min_value = int(min_entry.get())
    max_value = int(max_entry.get())
    input_value = int(input_size.get())

    data = []
    for _ in range(input_value):
        data.append(random.randint(min_value, max_value + 1))

    draw_data(data, ['Red' for _ in range(len(data))])


def draw_data(algo_data, color_list):
    sort_canvas.delete("all")

    canvas_height, canvas_width = 380, 500
    x_width = canvas_width / (len(algo_data) + 1)
    offset, spacing = 30, 10

    normalized_data = [i / max(algo_data) for i in algo_data]

    for i, height in enumerate(normalized_data):
        x0 = i * x_width + offset + spacing
        y0 = canvas_height - height * 340

        x1 = ((i + 1) * x_width + offset)
        y1 = canvas_height

        sort_canvas.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1, fill=color_list[i])
        sort_canvas.create_text(x0 + 2, y0, anchor='se', text=str(algo_data[i]))
    window.update()


def start_algorithm():
    global running_animation

    if not running_animation and navbar.curselection():
        running_animation = True

        speed_ms = int(sort_speed.get() * 1000)

        repeater(data, draw_data, speed_ms, generator)
        start_button.config(text='Stop')
    else:
        running_animation = False
        start_button.config(text='Start')


window = tk.Tk()
window.minsize(700, 580)

app_width, app_height = 700, 580
screen_width, screen_height = window.winfo_screenwidth(), window.winfo_screenheight()

mid_screen_x = (screen_width - app_width) // 2
mid_screen_y = (screen_height - app_height) // 2

window.title("StructViz")
window.iconbitmap("./assets/favicon.ico")
window.geometry(f'{app_width}x{app_height}+{mid_screen_x}+{mid_screen_y}')

select_alg = tk.StringVar()
data = []
generator = None
running_animation = False

window.columnconfigure(0, weight=0)
window.columnconfigure(1, weight=45)
window.rowconfigure((0, 1), weight=1)
window.rowconfigure(2, weight=45)

navbar = tk.Listbox(window, selectmode=tk.SINGLE, activestyle='none')
for item in ["Bubble sort", "Quick sort"]:
    navbar.insert(tk.END, item)
navbar.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=3, sticky='nsew')

user_settings = (tk.Frame(window, background='bisque2')
                 .grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2, rowspan=2, sticky='news', padx=7, pady=5))

algorithm = tk.Label(user_settings, text='No algorithm selected', background='bisque2')
algorithm.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nw', padx=10, pady=10)

time_complexity = tk.Label(user_settings, text='Time complexity: ', background='bisque2')
time_complexity.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='sw', padx=10, pady=10)

input_size = tk.Scale(user_settings, from_=5, to=60, label='Amount', background='bisque2',
                      orient=HORIZONTAL, resolution=1, cursor='arrow')
input_size.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='n', padx=10, pady=10)

min_entry = tk.Scale(user_settings, from_=0, to=10, resolution=1, background='bisque2',
                     orient=HORIZONTAL, label="Minimum Value")
min_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='s', padx=10, pady=10)

max_entry = tk.Scale(user_settings, from_=10, to=100, resolution=1, background='bisque2',
                     orient=HORIZONTAL, label="Maximum Value")
max_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='se', padx=10, pady=10)

sort_speed = tk.Scale(user_settings, from_=0.01, to=2.0, length=100, digits=3, background='bisque2',
                      resolution=0.01, orient=HORIZONTAL, label="Speed")
sort_speed.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ne', padx=10, pady=10)

start_button = (tk.Button(user_settings, text="Start", command=start_algorithm, background='bisque2'))
start_button.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='nw', padx=10, pady=10)

tk.Button(user_settings, text="Regenerate", command=regenerate, background='bisque2').grid(
    row=1, column=1, sticky='sw', padx=10, pady=10)

sort_canvas = tk.Canvas(window, background='bisque2')
sort_canvas.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='news', padx=5, pady=5)

window.mainloop()


Tried to make the sorting speed constant, but the program goes slow and fast at different times when visualizing quick sort.

the Tkinter module doesn't have a clock speed in the traditional sense. Tkinter itself doesn't directly control the processing speed of your program... perhaps you want to use pygame which does have a clock speed.

@D.L The window.after works fine in delaying operations. I just need it to actually affect the whole sorting process, which it doesn't appear to do.

The window.after will run some piece of code at a particular time. It WON'T stop  your code from running in the meantime. You have to rewrite your code so that each little piece of what your code does is called from window.after, then schedules another call to itself later. This is a lot of work. https://tkinter-async-execute.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.x/ may help.

Be warned, you'll have to twist your head around how async code works to do this project. You can't simply sprinkle some window.after calls, hope they will delay you, and have it work. That's because all that window.after does is enter something into a schedule for an event loop, and as soon as that is entered it returns and your code keeps running.

You need to apply delays to the swapping operations in the partition(), not the partition() itself. So, do like this.
...

def partition(data, draw_data, low, high):
    pivot = data[high]
    i = low - 1
    ...
    for j in range(low, high):

        if data[j] <= pivot:
            ...
            i += 1
            data[i], data[j] = data[j], data[i]
            yield
    ...
    data[i + 1], data[high] = data[high], data[i + 1]
    ...
    yield i + 1


def quick_sort(data, draw_data, low, high):
    if low < high:
        for item in partition(data, draw_data, low, high):
             if item is not None:
                 pivot_index = item
             yield

        yield from quick_sort(data, draw_data, low, pivot_index - 1)
        yield from quick_sort(data, draw_data, pivot_index + 1, high)

...

